# Error in deserializing body of reply message for a web service operation

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio

Error is obviously after the remote procedure/method has been executed. It's most likely that the remote service is sending back the incorrect data or so I think. I have tried increasing the readQuote in Web.Config, that didn't help.

**Response Class**

When this property (MultiSMSPostedList) is set, the value is NULL. As soon as the code comes out of get, the exception is thrown.

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "2.0.50727.5485")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    //[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn")]
    public partial class MessagingServices_SendMultiSMSResult : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private int sMSCountField;

        private MessagingServices_SendMultiSMS_SendSuccess[] multiSMSPostedListField;

        private MessagingServices_SendMultiSMS_SendFailed[] multiSMSRejectedListField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public int SMSCount {
            get {
                return this.sMSCountField;
            }
            set {
                this.sMSCountField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("SMSCount");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
        public MessagingServices_SendMultiSMS_SendSuccess[] MultiSMSPostedList {
            get {
                return this.multiSMSPostedListField;
            }
            set {
                this.multiSMSPostedListField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("MultiSMSPostedList");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
        public MessagingServices_SendMultiSMS_SendFailed[] MultiSMSRejectedList {
            get {
                return this.multiSMSRejectedListField;
            }
            set {
                this.multiSMSRejectedListField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("MultiSMSRejectedList");
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Exception**
The exception text is below, it clear that exception is caused when system tries to convert variable to array.
http://justpaste.it/sms-exception

**More information**
Further digging shows that the remote service is returning the correct number of values, if not the format.

This property **MultiSMSPostedList** makes call to below class based on the number of values passed to the original procedure/method. (i.e. if I pass two phone numbers and two text messages, the properties inside **MessagingServices_SendMultiSMS_SendSuccess** are initialized twice, indicating remote server returned an array)

**Property class**

```
public partial class MessagingServices_SendMultiSMS_SendSuccess : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private string gRecipientNameField;

        private string gRecipientMSISDNwithCCField;

        private int gOutMsgIDField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
        public string gRecipientName {
            get {
                return this.gRecipientNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.gRecipientNameField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("gRecipientName");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
        public string gRecipientMSISDNwithCC {
            get {
                return this.gRecipientMSISDNwithCCField;
            }
            set {
                this.gRecipientMSISDNwithCCField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("gRecipientMSISDNwithCC");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public int gOutMsgID {
            get {
                return this.gOutMsgIDField;
            }
            set {
                this.gOutMsgIDField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("gOutMsgID");
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

I am sure, visual studio is not able to generate the class correctly based on the WSDL data, I may need to make some changes to reference.cs file. I am not an expert on the subject, so not really sure what and where should I make the change?

**Could be useful**

Remote service is java based, axis web service.

**MORE INFO: Changes made to reference.cs**

I made below changes to **Response Class** and it's working without any exception. Since it's a variable instead of array, I get only first response and all the other response values are lost.

```
private MessagingServices_SendMultiSMS_SendSuccess[] multiSMSPostedListField;

private MessagingServices_SendMultiSMS_SendFailed[] multiSMSRejectedListField;
```

I am not sure where exactly in the reference.cs I can find the location, where remote call is made/ends, may be making some changes there could help. Any suggestions?

Comment: It could be a known bug where an array is incorrectly generated from the WSDL: http://webservices20.blogspot.de/2010/02/net-wcf-bug-cannot-convert-type-to.html

Comment: @nodots I tried to do what is explained in the article, it didn't help. Still getting the same error, after making all the changes. Also, the remote service is an apache axis not a WCF.